# Link all C++ lib dependencies into a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll, lib

So I'm trying to compile a VS project into a dll but I can't seem to get all the .lib dependencies to be included with the dll.

[image: Linker settings]

[image: Include options]

[image: Depencency walker output]

Comment: Dependency walker is not accurate anymore, it has not kept pace with Windows. However, what are you actually trying to do here. These dependencies, are they static or dynamic?

Comment: The depencancies are .lib files, and I'm trying to make a dll file that runs the code without libcrypro, libexpat, ... dlls to be installed on the system.

Comment: That's not going to work. Install the dependencies alongside your own code. Also, there are two types of lib file. A static lib which contains code. You can link those into your code without requiring DLLs. And an import lib which is used to link implicitly to a DLL. I expect you have import libs.

Comment: Link Library Dependencies is a configuration for a multi-project solution. Ex: You're building a solution with two projects, a dll project 'foo' that produces 'foo.dll' and an exe project 'prog' that produces 'prog.exe'. In the Project Dependencies Configuration of the solution you can set the 'foo' project to be a dependency of 'proj'. By doing that *and* setting "Link Library Dependencies' to Yes in the 'prog' project configuration, the project manager will automagically link any lib(s) produced by 'foo' to 'proj' when 'proj' is built.

Comment: The .lib file extension is used for two types of files: Import libraries, containing only the exported symbols alongside the information which module exports them, as well as static libraries. Static libraries contain both the exported symbols as well as their object code. It seems you are trying to solve a problem that requires the second type of .lib files, but you are using the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the solution thanks to David Heffernan and IInspectable.

I was using import .lib files, and not static.
Got it working with static libs.